Laravel Policy Method `can_methodname` is not working
Currently our system has roles and permissions and its already been running for years. We've been using spatie/laravel-permission package
Our permission name has the following format: can_permission_name
Anyway I'm creating a Laravel policy, let's say UserPolicy
class UserPolicy
{
    public function can_add_user(User $user): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}

And I have a method can_add_user, and I added it as a middleware
Route::get("users/{user}", [UserController::class, "add"])->middleware(["can:can_add_user,user"]);

But I think appending can_ into the method doesn't seem to be working. How can I make this work, I want to name the method in this format can_method_name?

using can_ as policy method name prefix is wrong, i mean can:can_add_user reads wrong, right. You should avoid adding _can. Anyways, you need to modify the gate logic for policy matching.

In this code want code in AuthServiceProvider. please try out this.
 class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];
}



Route::get("users/{user}", [UserController::class, "add"])- 
  >middleware("can:add_user,user");


I want my method name to be can_add_user

Please explain how this would solve the issue at hand. "try this" is not an answer, furthermore, code-only answers are not good answers anyway
